# How to keep the data in the text fields until the form has been submitted successfully

Tags: java, forms, validation, struts-1

I am using struts1.3 to develop application.While adding data to the database I will do both client side server validation. When validation happen at server side like duplication checking or some other business validation, if the data is duplicate in the form it will give error message but the data what I have entered in the text fields will not come back again, the user need to fill the form again. could anyone please help me how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I think in `<action .................... scope="session">` will help you out for this problem.

Comment: I need to add in the struts.xml file

Comment: The data is not held in the form

Comment: if reset() method is called ??? otherwise there is no reason data is not held in form.

Comment: <input type="text" name="deptname" maxlength="30" id="deptname" class="input-xlarge focused" style="height:27px;" value="${param.deptname}"/>

Comment: I have made the scope as session and in the text field i written  value="${param.deptname}" for text box its coming now but in the select box is not coming.

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev Struts 1, not Struts 2. And the answer is particularly confusing since in Struts 2 which you link to there's no such attribute `scope`.

Comment: <action
                path="/LogonSubmit"
                type="app.LogonAction"
                name="logonForm"
                scope="request"
                validate="true"
                input="/pages/Logon.jsp">
                <forward
                    name="success"
                    path="/pages/Welcome.jsp"/>
                <forward
                    name="failure"
                    path="/pages/Logon.jsp"/>
            </action>

Comment: see here the scope is request scope="request"

Comment: scope="request" replace with scope="session"

Comment: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-login-page-example-1.html